# Configure a new coordinate reference in Leaflet

Tags: javascript, leaflet, gis

I'm trying to implement Leaflet for a game map. It kinda works with L.CRS.Simple. However, in the game, the "southwest" corner should be [0,0], while the "northeast" corner should be [10000,10000] (it's a square map).

How do I tell Leaflet to use this as a coordinate system?

Answer (score 0):

Try to change Leaflet's CRS transform like this:

```
L.CRS.Simple.transformation = L.transformation(scale_x, shift_x, scale_y, shift_y);
```

scale_x, scale_y in my case is 1, you may need change scale_y to -1.